# Challenging inequality: $abcde=1$, show that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{e}+\frac{33}{2(a+b+c+d+e)}\ge{\frac{{83}}{10}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, lagrange-multiplier, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c,d,e$ be positive real numbers which satisfy $abcde=1$. How can one prove that:
$$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{d} +\frac{1}{e}+ \frac{33}{2(a + b + c + d+e)} \ge{\frac{{83}}{10}}\ \ ?$$

Comment: "Hoc" as in "ad hoc"?

Comment: Maybe he ment "How"

Comment: -1: I think it would be nice if you started including some information on what *you* tried to do before asking the question here. Randomly checking among your 40 questions so far revealed *not a single* question that wasn't only a copy of a problem from some IMO-style list.

Comment: Putting $a:=x$, $b:=x$, $c:=y$, $d:=y$ $e:=x^{-2}y^{-2}$ and plotting the left side of the stated inequality one obtains a nonconvex surface. This indicates that simple convexity arguments won't do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is only a partial solution but I think someone more familiar with such elementary inequalities than myself might be able to finish it. You can replace $a,b,c,d$, and $e$ with their reciprocals and the inequality in question becomes
$$a + b + c + d + e + {33 \over 2}{1 \over ({1 \over a} + {1 \over b} + {1 \over c} + {1 \over d} + {1 \over e})} \geq {83 \over 10}$$
Since still $abcde = 1$, we can rewrite this as 
$$a + b + c + d + e + {33 \over 2}{1 \over ({1 \over a} + {1 \over b} + {1 \over c} + {1 \over d} + {1 \over e})} \geq {83 \over 10}(abcde)^{1 \over 5}$$
Some algebra converts this into 
$${a + b + c + d + e \over 5} - (abcde)^{1 \over 5} \geq {33 \over 50}(abcde)^{1 \over 5} - {33 \over 50}{5 \over ({1 \over a} + {1 \over b} + {1 \over c} + {1 \over d} + {1 \over e})}$$
In other words, $AM - GM \geq {33 \over 50}(GM - HM)$. This is needed only when $abcde = 1$, but by scaling this should then hold for all $a,b,c,d,$ and $e$. So you inequality experts out there... is this something that follows from well-known inequalities?

Answer (score 1):

Replace with reciprocals so the problem becomes

$a + b + c + d + e + {33 \over 2}{1 \over {1 \over a} + {1 \over b} + {1 \over c} + {1 \over d} + {1 \over e}} \geq {83 \over 10}$

Sort the numbers so that $a\le b\le c\le d\le e$ and assume that $a,b,c,d,e$ are not all equal to $1$. Since $a<1$ and $e>1$ we have
$(a+b+c+d+e) - (1+b+c+d+ea) = a+e-1-ae = (e-1)(1-a) > 0$

Let $x_1=\frac{1}{a}+ \frac{1}{b}+ \frac{1}{c}+ \frac{1}{d}+ \frac{1}{e}$ and $x_2=\frac{1}{1}+ \frac{1}{b}+ \frac{1}{c}+ \frac{1}{d}+ \frac{1}{ea}$

$x_1 - x_2 = \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{ea} - 1 = \frac{(e-1)(1-a)}{ea} >0$

The geometric harmonic inequality says $(bcdea)^{1/5}\ge \frac{5}{\frac{1}{1}+ \frac{1}{b}+ \frac{1}{c}+ \frac{1}{d}+ \frac{1}{ea}} $ and thus using $abcde=1$ we conclude $\frac{1}{5}\ge \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1}+ \frac{1}{b}+ \frac{1}{c}+ \frac{1}{d}+ \frac{1}{ea}}$. Thus we have that $x_2\ge 5$.

The mean value theorem applied to the function $f(x)=1/x$ gives

$\frac{1}{x_1}-\frac{1}{x_2} = f'(\theta)(x_1-x_2)$ where $x_2 \le\theta\le x_1$. This tells us that since $\theta\ge x_2\ge 5$ that $f'(\theta)\ge f'(x_2) \ge f'(5) = -\frac{1}{5^2}$

Since $bcde=1/a$ we cannot have $b,c,d,e$ all less than $1/a^{1/4}$. As $e$ is the largest of them we must have $e\ge 1/a^{1/4}$ and since $0\le a\le 1$ we can conclude $ea\ge a^{3/4}\ge 1$.

Now putting all the computations above together gives
$\left(a+b+c+d+e+\frac{33}{2}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{e}}\right) - \left(1+b+c+d+ea+\frac{33}{2}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{ea}}\right) =$
$(e-1)(1-a) + \frac{33}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x_1}-\frac{1}{x_2}\right)= (e-1)(1-a) + \frac{33}{2}f'(\theta)(x_1-x_2) =$
$(e-1)(1-a) + \frac{33}{2}f'(\theta)\frac{(e-1)(1-a)}{ea}\ge (e-1)(1-a) - \frac{33}{50}\frac{(e-1)(1-a)}{ea}\ge $

$(e-1)(1-a) - \frac{33}{50}(e-1)(1-a) = \frac{27}{50}(e-1)(1-a)\ge 0$

Thus if we replace $a,b,c,d,e$ with $1,b,c,d,ea$ the left hand side of the inequality decreases while still maintaining $abcde=1$. We sort the numbers $1,b,c,d,ea$ and choose the smallest and largest among them and repeat the process we have just described. Eventually all five numbers will become 1 thus showing

$a+b+c+d+e+\frac{33}{2}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{e}} \ge 1+b+c+d+ea+\frac{33}{2}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{ea}}\ge \ldots \ge$

$1+1+1+1+1+\frac{33}{2}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}}=\frac{83}{10}$

Comment: I don't see how $ea\ge a^{3/4} \ge 1$ follows; with $a\le 1$ this would require $a=1$.

Comment: Oh you're right that is a mistake. Unfortunately I don't see how to repair the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the Vasc's EV Method.

See here: https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf

Indeed, let $a+b+c+d+e=constant.$

Thus,  by corollary 1.9, case 1(b) ($p=0$,$q=-1$)

the expression $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{a}$ gets a minimal value for equality case of four variables.

Id est, it remains to prove our inequality for $b=c=d=e$ and $a=\frac{1}{e^4}$, which gives
$$(e-1)^2(40e^8+80e^7+120e^6+160e^5-132e^4-89e^3-46e^2-3e+40)\geq0,$$
which is true because $$40e^8+80e^7+120e^6+160e^5-132e^4-89e^3-46e^2-3e+40=$$
$$=40(e^4+e^3+e^2-3e+1)^2+e(320e^4-12e^3+71e^2-486e+237)\geq$$
$$\geq e((e^2+40.5)(3e-2)^2+311e^4-297.5e^2+75)>0$$ and the last inequality is true because $$297.5^2-4\cdot311\cdot75=297.5^2-311\cdot300<0.$$

Comment: Wait, $\mathbb{R}_{+}^5$ is not compact actually? As it is not bounded (even if you extend $f$ to $0$ via a limit).

Comment: @DesmondMiles You are right. Thank you for your points! We can end the proof by the Lagrange multipliers method, of course. I have found an easier reasoning and posted a solution, for which we have one case only. See now, please.